# Best way to handle large data in c++?

Tags: c++, sql, large-data

I have a very large number of objects (about 30k). What is the best way to store and access them? They all have a specific Id, but i also would like to filter and search for them with their name, category etc. Its a quite simple class, something like the following:

```
class objclass {
int id;
std::string name;
...
}
```

I was thinking about SQL, but I don't know if thats the best way.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Update: Thx Guys! I think i'll go with a vector then. And thx for clarifying that 30k isnt that big^^ For me, who never handled with such amounts of Data it seemed quite large ;)

Comment: There is never a *best* way. Only the way which works best for *you*.

Comment: I don't think this is much data. Just store them in a vector, make sure to `shrink_to_fit` the vector. If there are a lot of duplicate `name`/`category` strings, use a flyweight. Sort them on the `id` for fast searches. Maybe use a container of iterators and sort it on the `category` or whatever to have fast searches on this.

Comment: And 30k elements don't seem to be a very large number of objects^^

Comment: Is that temporary storage in memory (in which case I'd probably use something like [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), or just cobble something together with vectors and maps) or persistent storage (in which case a database is probably the best option - I like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/), but there are plenty of others)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` sounds like a perfect fit. If you know in advance how many elements you get, use `vector::reserve` or `vector::resize` to not overallocate. Otherwise use `vector::shrink_to_fit` after lots of insertions.

To speed up searches on the `id`, sort the `vector` on it and use a `binary_search/lower_bound`.

If you have lots of strings with the same content, use a flyweight class. This can also substantially speed up string comparisons.

To search quickly on string members, get a `vector` of iterators into your container and sort those or go for a `boost::multi_index`.

A small calculation to back that up: assuming `int` is 4 bytes, your strings average 20 letters, 30 000 elements, makes roughly 2 megabyte. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

30.000 objects isn't really a "very large number". As long as the objects themself aren't several kB in size, the whole set should still fit into RAM easily, so there is really no reason to use a database just because of the size.

You could store them all in an `std::vector`. When you need to search them efficiently, you could create a `std::map` or `std::multimap` for each field you want to search for which maps values to references to your objects.

There might, however, be other reasons to use a database besides the amount of data. For example when you have other programs (or multiple instances of the same program) which operate on the same data and want to keep the data synchronized between them. Or when you just want a reliable persistence layer. Which database to choose is really up to you. Your requirements (as far as you wrote them) are so generic that any database system should be able to handle them adequately. There might be some aspects of your project which make some databases more fitting than others, but you didn't mention any.

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL-Database will probably be fine. 30k is not a "very large number", what makes you think that it is?

Unless your filter criterion are very complex you might also consider keeping everything in memory. That is if you don't need persistence of some kind, but your requirements are very vague.

So: if you want to go for convenience I'd choose SQL, if speed is *very* important I'd go for an in-memory version and custom filters. But that depends on the kind of data you have and a lot of other factors.

Answer (score -1):

You should find a way which suits you the best. SQLite, MySQL databases could be used for large database requirements with C++

Comment: Why would that be OK here?

Comment: What do you think is the best way to store 30K objects? You want to crash the program by storing them all in the exe itself?

Comment: 30k objects of the type OP described is literally nothing. The only reason to get a DB is persistence and even then hand-coding the serialization is going to be faster and less of a hassle.

Comment: So what makes you think using a SQLite file is a hassle and slower task? you should be encouraging best practices not easy practices right?

Comment: Yes, and I'm convinced it is not a good practice to get a dependency on a database if all you are doing is handling a small homogeneous collection of objects.

Comment: we are not depending on a database as SQLite is a simple db file which is meant to be created for small database usages. It is more efficient and reduces the complexity of the program and increases readability. You don't want to tie up everything in the code just because you can.

Answer (score -3):

I think creating a database would be the best.

Comment: And why do you think that?

Comment: And what about std::vector?